# Wordpress Plugins: Amazon S3 and CloudFront + NextGen Gallery

Tags: wordpress

I've recently added a great plugin to my Wordpress install: Amazon S3 and CloudFront to serve all my images from Cloudfront.

While this works wonderfully - I am having issues with NextGen Gallery.

This appear to be a common issue.  It seems that the Cloudfront plugin changes the URLS stored and associated with each image upload via NextGen - however the actual images never get pushed up to Cloudfront.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I might be able to prevent Nextgen from using the Cloudfront plugin and use the standard Wordpress image upload method / Alternatively any suggestions on how I can get Nextgen to behave with this plugin.

Thanks.